# CSS does not apply on div

Tags: javascript, html, css

The CSS rules for `header` don't apply in Chrome or Firefox, but `section` does, and strangely both work in JSFiddle.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1>Test</h1>
</div>

<div id="section">
    <p>test</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
<style>
#header {
    background-color: #f0fff0;
    color: #262626;
    text-align: center;
}
#section {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efLt0ahz/)

Comment: Do you have those `<style>` tags in the external CSS file as well? Why?

Comment: Why does your CSS file have style tags? There is no HTML is a .css file.

Comment: Is your stylesheet loading properly? (I'm saying it is NOT).  Open the page in your browser.  View Source.  Typically, the "style.css" in the stylesheet link becomes clickable (in view source).  Click the link.  Does it load?  Or is it 404?

Comment: @qwr have you seen your web inspector console to identify any obvious errors, such as having HTML inside your .css file: `<style>` tag is invalid

Comment: @cale_b it loads as plaintext

Comment: @AGE chrome gives no errors

Comment: @cale_b yes that solved it, I am new to CSS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML is not valid inside of a stylesheet.

maybe remove

```
<style>
</style>
```

in your .css file

Comment: Indeed. A quick and dirty test shows that this is apparently an unrecoverable error, in both browsers.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your html file and style.css are in the same directory.